# NodeJS/MongoDB - Match Value in Array with a Value from a Logged In User

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I want Users to be able to Report a File/Video only once. By pushing the users ID to a Array, then check if the user has already reported the file.
So far I am able  to find the current user, then the VideoID, increment by 1 and then push it to the reportedBy array. But I am pretty lost, when it comes to checking if the current user has already reported the file. Any tips/help will be much appreciated! :-)

**MY ROUTE**

```
router.get('/report/:videoLink', function(req, res, next){
 async.waterfall([
   function(callback){
     User.findOne({_id: req.user._id}, function(err, foundUser){
       if(err) return next(err)
       callback(err, foundUser)
     })
   },
   function(foundUser, callback){
     Video.findOne({videoLink: req.params.videoLink}, function(err, reportVideo){
         reportVideo.reports++;
         reportVideo.reportedBy.push(foundUser);

       if (reportVideo.reports > 4) {
         reportVideo.remove();
       }
         reportVideo.save(function(err){
           if(err) return next();
         });
         res.redirect('/');
     });

  }
 ]);
 });
```

**MY SCHEMA**

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var random = require('mongoose-simple-random');


    var fragSchema = new Schema({

      title: String,
      videoLink: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
      category: String,
      upVotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
      downVotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
      voted: {type: Boolean, default: false},
      reports: {type: Number, default: 0},
      reportedBy: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
      ownByUser: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
      date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }

    });
    fragSchema.plugin(random);

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Frag', fragSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should find the video only if it was reported by that user before:

```
Video.findOne({
    videoLink: req.params.videoLink,
    reportedBy: foundUser._id,
}, ...
```

and this should find the video only if it was not reported before:

```
Video.findOne({
    videoLink: req.params.videoLink,
    reportedBy: {$nin: [foundUser._id]},
}, ...
```

There are many ways to achieve that but you get the idea.

If you want to find the video anyway an then test if it was already reported by that user then something like this inside of your `Video.findOne` callback:

```
if (reportVideo.reportedBy.indexOf(foundUser._id) < 0) {
    // not reported by that user yet
} else {
    // already reported by that user
}
```

If you're using `lodash` then you can use:

```
if (_.includes(reportVideo.reportedBy, foundUser._id)) {
    // already reported by that user
} else {
    // not reported by that user yet
}
```

Make sure that you have the IDs as strings, maybe you will need to use `.toString()` or something like that before the comparisons.

Comment: Thanks alot! Exactly what I was looking for! I tested all three, and they all did the job! :)